Role of に in もどかしさに喉の奥から叫び声が迸ってしまいそうな感情
I am uncertain about the role of に here:

もどかしさに喉の奥から叫び声が迸ってしまいそうな感情

I initially thought もどかしさ is where 叫び声 will end up in. But I think it is better to understand the に in もどかしさに as a reason or cause for 喉の奥から叫び声が迸る. Is that right?

Exactly! This に is a reason marker used with psychological reactions. In this case, you can read it as "because of もどかしさ".
Related:

に in コントロールに苦しまなくなった
What is the difference between the に used here and で when specifying a reason for a future action?

